# Explain why integral by test cannot be used to determine convergence/ divergence of the series.

Tags: calculus

The given series is $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos ^2 n}{1+n^2}$. In order to use integral test, the function must be positive, continuous and decreasing on $[1,\infty)$. I realize that it is positive and continuous, what I am struggling with is determining if it is decreasing. This is what I have: I wanted to use the first derivative test.

Let $f(n)=\frac{\cos ^2 n}{1+n^2}$, then

$f^\prime(n)=-\frac{2  }{n^2+1}\left(\cos( n)\sin (n)+\frac{n\cos ^2 n}{1+n^2}\right)$

If there is $n$ in $[1,\infty)$ that would make what's in the bracket negative, then the function would not be decreasing hence integral test cannot be used. In short, I am struggling to solve

$\cos( n)\sin (n)+\frac{n\cos ^2 n}{1+n^2}<0$

Comment: @Randall is that obvious? i was using first derivative test to establish that and I got stuck

Comment: I agree with you that it's not obvious, so I deleted my comment.  My answer below gives a more direct way to show that $f$ does not decrease

Answer (score 1):

Integral test doesn't work here simply because $f(x)=\frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+x^2}$ is not decreasing. But the convergence of this series is more obvious. It converges because
$$0\leq \frac{\cos^2(n)}{1+n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Comment: In principle, if you only know that f(x) is not decreasing you can not infer that f(n) is not decreasing. It is very easy to produce examples of this situation. Of course the series is convergent by your inequalities.

Comment: @Luca: sure, but to use intgral principal, $f(x)$ must be decreasing, not only $f(n)$

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to play with $y$-coordinates and not the derivative.  Note that $f(0)=1$, $f(\pi/2) =0$, and  $f(\pi)=\frac{1}{1+\pi^2} >0$, so $f$ does not decrease (nor does it increase).  If you don't want to include $f(0)$ in the argument, it doesn't matter since the latter two points show this fails to decrease on $[1, +\infty)$.  Hence you may not apply the Integral Test.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be convinced that your function, for $x\in[1,+\infty)$ is not decreasing.

So you want to solve the inequality in OP. These are some *hints:*

Multiply both sides by $1+x^2,$ write $\sin x\cos x=\frac12\sin 2x$ and $\cos^2x=\frac12(1+\cos 2x).$ Then combine the sines and cosines (which now have equal arguments) using $$\sin y+\cos y=\sqrt 2\sin(y+π/4).$$